# saving managedObject new relationship object wont animate to UITableView

Tags: ios, animation, core-data, uitableview

When I'm adding a new object to my core data entity, it wont animate into my uitableview.
tried lots of things, added an integer for my if statement to see if there were changes to my managedobject and yes, it does go in the if statement.
I can somewhat later call reloadData and it will put the missing cell in the tableview but I want to do that with animation of course.

When exactly should I put the insertRow method ? 
I tried at many points yet I get an error that i'm attempting to add a fifth row while there are only 4 after the update or something.

```
    - (void)insertNewObject
{
    int count = [self.detailItem.catRelations count];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void)
                  {
                      NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

                      NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                      newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];


                      [newManagedObject setImageMetaData:localImageMetaData];
                      [newManagedObject setImageItself:localImageItself];
                      [newManagedObject setImageCreationDate:[NSDate date]];
                      [newManagedObject setImageName:localImageTitle];
                      newManagedObject.imageRelations = self.detailItem;
                      // Save the context.
                      NSError *error = nil;
                      if (![context save:&error]) {
                          NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                          abort();
                      }


                      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                                    {
                                        if (count != self.detailItem.catRelations.count)
                                        {

                                            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count+1 inSection:0];
                                            [imagesTV insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
                                        }

                                    });
                  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am still gaining rep here I cannot comment to ask questions. But I can give a few pointers and possibly clear things up.

**First**

You may want to look into `NSFetchedResultsController`. It will help you manage your data, using predicates and delegates to insert/update/delete data from your tableview. While manually doing so is a valid solution you may want to consider FRC's. Here is a [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) to how to use FRCs.

**Second**

Its good you are doing core data work in the background. On the flip side, if you are adding only 1 object into core data in a relatively small database you may not be buying yourself as much as you may think. What worries me is the call to `self.managedObjectContext`. Since you are on the background thread you should make sure that context is safe to be used in the background. Also, after you are saving it (assuming its properly set up as a background context) I don't see where you are merging it into the foreground context. If you think you'll need that background context after all, be sure to read up on [concurrency and core data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html).